# Amazon rds Aurora clone/restore point in time API

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

When I try to use clone/restore point in time from amazon console. It clones cluster as well as all the instances which belongs to that. But  when I consume the same functionality using amazon API, it clones only cluster alone.

Is there any other API to clone cluster alone with their instances, security/parameter group and other settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console adds a convenience layer where in it internally makes multiple API calls to make the experience better. Restoring from a snapshot or from point in time is done in 2 steps:

1. `RestoreDBClusterFromSnapshot` or `RestoreDBClusterToPointInTime` API - To create a new cluster, backed by a new distributed aurora volume. No DB instances are added when then API is issued.
2. `CreateDBInstance` API - To add instances to the cluster.

So in short, if you want to do it via CLI, you need to issue both these API calls. The same is true while creating a cluster with instances as well. Console would create a cluster and add instances in the same UX workflow, but behind the scenes, it is actually issuing a `CreateDBCluster` API followed by one or more `CreateDBInstance` API call(s).

Hope this helps.